# some question about RGBD-6D-SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to achieve RGBD-6D-SLAM, but do not know the hardware configuration to run this program requires.As much detail as possible, my computer graphics card is Intel GMA HD 3000.Intel Core i5 2520M, 2.5GHz.I hope to get your reply, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41371/some-question-about-rgbd-6d-slam/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I know, Ubuntu does not support intel graphic card very well. My GMA950 graphic card cannot get 3D acceleration support under Ubuntu and the system freezing when I launch the program. You'd better check your driver support for the graphic card.
AMD should be the best choice for the graphic card.
It works well with my two years laptop, lenovo T410 with a NVidia graphic card after I have updated the driver.

---

edit:
Note for myself also.

if you wanna check whether your laptop is suitable for OpenGL,

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

and you will see something like

```
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 660/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.96

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

if the unity 3D supported is no, definitely it won't work well.

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can run RGBDSLAM with your system, I have a very similiar laptop and I am able to run it. However, having an NVIDIA graphics card with Cuda technology would improve the accuracy of the method since you would be able to run SIFTGPU. There is a number of ways you could improve the speed of RGBDSLAM on your system (but possibly loosing some accuracy). Using ORB features instead of SIFT and SURF is usually faster. Also running the command `rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui` then selecting camera/driver from the list and setting the frames per second to `QVGA 30Hz` instead of the `VGA 30Hz` will significantly improve the speed. You could also reduce the maximum number of features detected and some other configurations to increase the speed of this method.

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5